# Add disable attribute on select options using function return html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, laravel-5

I am using this function to add option in to select box. Options are added successfully but i don't know to add extra attribute using function. so how can i add extra attribute like disable `<option value="0" disable>Select Fee Head</option>` on first option which value is 0.

## function

```
public function feeHtmlRow()
    {
        $fee_heads = [];
        $fee_heads[0] = 'Select Fee Head';
        foreach (FeeHead::select('id', 'fee_head_title')->get() as $fees) {
            $fee_heads[$fees->id] = $fees->fee_head_title;
        }
        $response['html'] = view($this->view_path.'.includes.fee_tr', [
            'fee_heads' => $fee_heads
        ])->render();
        return response()->json(json_encode($response));

    }
```

## Jquery

```
$('#load-html-btn').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{ route('account.fees.master.fee-html') }}',
                data: {
                    _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    var data = $.parseJSON(response);

                    if (data.error) {
                       // $.notify(data.message, "warning");
                    } else {

                        $('#fee_wrapper').append(data.html);
                        //$.notify(data.message, "success");

                    }
                }
            });

        });
```

## output

```
<select class="form-control" required="" name="fee_head[]">
     <option value="0">Select Fee Head</option>
     <option value="2">APPLICATION FORM</option>
     <option value="1">MONTHLY FEE</option>
     <option value="4">REGISTRATION FEE</option>
     <option value="3">TUTION FEE</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You aren't showing how the `<select>` is generated

Answer (score 2):

Using `jQuery`, select the first option and disable it,  or you can just add `disable` to your first option, when you generate the `select`

```js
$('option[value="0"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" required="" name="fee_head[]">
  <option value="0">Select Fee Head</option>
  <option value="2">APPLICATION FORM</option>
  <option value="1">MONTHLY FEE</option>
  <option value="4">REGISTRATION FEE</option>
  <option value="3">TUTION FEE</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE**

After appending your options, use `$(document).find('option[value="0"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");` to disable the first option.

```
$('#load-html-btn').click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{ route('account.fees.master.fee - html') }}',
            data: {
                _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
            },
            success: function (response) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(response);

                if (data.error) {
                    // $.notify(data.message, "warning");
                } else {

                    $('#fee_wrapper').append(data.html);
                    //$.notify(data.message, "success");
                    // disable the first option after appending the select
                    $(document).find('option[value="0"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: When can i add $('option[value="0"]').attr("disabled", "disabled"); on my jquery

Comment: @UmeshYadav if this has solved your problem, please select it as answer.